# App crashes after adding FirebaseAuth.getInstance

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I had added firebase authentication yesterday and it was working fine but today after editing some files it is crashing.
App only crashes when I add  "firebaseAuth =FirebaseAuth.getInstance()".
If I remove it then all things work fine but now I cannot add firebase.

> SignUp.java

```
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;

public class SignUp extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private TextView alreadyRegistered;
    private EditText mEmailView;
    private EditText mPasswordView;
    private Button signup;
    private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sign_up);

        progressDialog=new ProgressDialog(this);

        mEmailView =  (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email_signup);

        mPasswordView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password_signup);

        signup=(Button)findViewById(R.id.signup);

        alreadyRegistered=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.already_registered);

//        firebaseAuth =FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
////        if(firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() != null){
////            //that means user is already logged in
////            //so close this activity
////            finish();
////
////            //and open profile activity
////            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Home.class));
////        }

        alreadyRegistered.setOnClickListener(this);
        signup.setOnClickListener(this);

    }
    private void registerUser() {

        //getting email and password from edit texts
        String email = mEmailView.getText().toString().trim();
        String password = mPasswordView.getText().toString().trim();

        //checking if email and passwords are empty
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email)) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter email", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }

        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(password)) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter password", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }


        //if the email and password are not empty
        //displaying a progress dialog

        progressDialog.setMessage("Registering Please Wait...");
        progressDialog.show();

        //creating a new user
        firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        //checking if success
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            //display some message here
                            Toast.makeText(SignUp.this, "Successfully registered", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            Intent intent = new Intent(SignUp.this, MainActivity.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        } else {
                            //display some message here
                            Toast.makeText(SignUp.this, "Registration Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
//                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        if(v==signup)
        {
            registerUser();
        }
        if(v==alreadyRegistered)
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(SignUp.this,MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
}
```

I tried debugging and it  crashes when I run that particular line.

> Crash Logs

```
2019-02-16 14:43:23.569 25053-25053/com.example.android.nirog E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.android.nirog, PID: 25053
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.android.nirog/com.example.android.nirog.SignUp}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process com.example.android.nirog. Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first.
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2949)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3027)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1745)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:200)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6956)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:519)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:836)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process com.example.android.nirog. Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first.
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.getInstance(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@16.0.2:240)
        at com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.getInstance(Unknown Source:1)
        at com.example.android.nirog.SignUp.onCreate(SignUp.java:44)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7225)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7216)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1215)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2902)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3027) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1745) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:200) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6956) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:519) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:836) 
2019-02-16 14:43:23.623 25053-25053/com.example.android.nirog I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 25053 SIG: 9
```

Comment: So why you didn't post crash logs? Try to post it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most helpful in android with fluuter and firebase

in app level `build.gradle`

```
 defaultConfig {      

    minSdkVersion 23

}
```

in project level `gradle.properties` add

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536M
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
android.enableR8=true
```

in `build.gradle` add

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
}
```

you can skip that Kotlin plugin if you are not using Kotlin support
Dont forget to run `flutter clean` and then `flutter pub upgrade`

These changes helped me preventing my app crashes, It should help you too.

Answer (score 1):

You have not initialised firebase. Add this in `onCreate` of your SignUp class

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sign_up);
         FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context)
```

Comment: I have tried it but this also didn't work. The thing that worked is changing this 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0' to this ' com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first in Android method added in MyApplication class in your project like :

```
override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
{
FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context);

}
```